# Convert a TXT file to float array python

Tags: python, arrays, import, txt

I have TXT file with float numbers.

I can not convert it to float array in python.

```
f = open('Vmat.txt', 'r')
DATA = f.read()
DATA = DATA.split("\n")
for i in range(0,len(DATA),1):
    DATA[i] = DATA[i].replace(",","")
    DATA[i] = float(DATA[i])
```

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

ipython-input-73-e205bb7634f9   in   module

4 for i in range(0,len(DATA),1):

5     DATA[i] = DATA[i].replace(",","")

----> 6     DATA[i] = float(DATA[i])

ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Answer (score 0):

The error message states that you are trying to cast an empty string ('') to a float which is impossible. This is probably because you have an empty line at the end of your file.

Answer (score 0):

```py
f = open('Vmat.txt', 'r')
DATA = f.read()
DATA = DATA.split("\n")
for i in range(0,len(DATA),1):
    if not DATA[i]:
        continue
    DATA[i] = DATA[i].replace(",","")
    DATA[i] = float(DATA[i])
```

This might work if the program crashes at the end because of an empty line.

Why are you replacing a comma with nothing? How will it keep its float value and not turn into a integer? `DATA[i] = DATA[i].replace(",","")` might also help

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('Vmat.txt', 'r') 
DATA = f.read() 
DATA = DATA.split("\n") 
NEW_DATA = []
for i in DATA: 
   try: 
      if float(i): 
         NEW_DATA.append(float(i))  
   except ValueError: 
      print("Not float value")
print(NEW_DATA)
```